# subprocess.check_output apparently not capturing output

Tags: python, windows

I'm running a simple python script like this:

```
C:\workspace\MetaPackager\src\metapackager_tests\fake_project\src>c:\workspace\MetaPackager\Scripts\python.exe -c "print 'hello world'"
hello world
```

When I try to run the exact same thing from within subprocess.check_poutput I get nothing:

```
C:\workspace\MetaPackager\src\metapackager_tests\fake_project\src>c:\workspace\MetaPackager\Scripts\python.exe
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> import sys
>>> args = [sys.executable, '-c', '"print(\'hello world\')"']
>>> subprocess.check_output(args).strip()
''
```

This also produces the exact same kind of failure:

```
subprocess.check_output(args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,).strip()
''
```

Can anybody see what might be going wrong?

This is 32bit Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Try: `args = [sys.executable, '-c', 'print(\'hello world\')']` or simply `args = [sys.executable, '-c', 'print("hello world")']` -- both work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to write like this:

```
 subprocess.check_output(["python", "-c", "print 'hello'"])
```

Here is detail [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for `subprocess.check_output`.

Answer (score 0):

Too much quoting, this works:

```
    subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-c', '__import__("sys").stdout.write(\'Hello\')'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```